# i want to have a unique url for each users in my site using cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i want to have a unique url for each users in my site with cakephp, www.domain.com/testuser.
but with url above it will search for a controller action testuser. How can i route www.domain.com/testuser to user controller index action with testuser as paramter.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this section](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Configuration.html#routes-configuration) of the CakePHP 1.3 book. It explains how routing works. You'll have to have a route that first checks for the usernames slug and connect it with a controller and action, then all other routes.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply. but how can we create a route which first checks the usernames and the to all other routes as you have mentioned??

Comment: Did you even try to read more than the first sentence of the page I've linked? What you want is described there. http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Configuration.html#custom-route-classes You need a custom route class and use that to lookup the slug so that the route can return true or false to match the URL or not.

Answer (score 0):

www.domain.com has some default controller and action, lets say pagescontroller and index function, now you want www.domain.com/testuser url so create one more action within the same controller named userProfile(), Now you have to direct all the request to this action from www.domain.com/ANYTHING.....

You can use unique string in place of ANYTHING or add unique ID to ANYTHING_546 which will solve your purpose.

www.domain.com/unique_ANYTHING
www.domain.com/ANYTHING-36352